# How to use core java to implement the mechanism JNDI?

Tags: java, sockets

I ensure myself that I understand why we use JNDI to fetch objects that we want to use in our application and know its power. But my question is how does for example Tomcat or Jboss implement this feature?

If giving me a chance I would use socket to implement such as below:

```
Client side: 
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",10000);
//get a Person Object
socket.write("JNDI/Person")


Server side :
ServerSocket socketServer = new ServerSocket("localhost", 10000);
string str= socket.read();
if(str.equals("JNDI/Person")){
  //ok I return back you a Person object.

 socketServer.write(new Person());
}
```

Is this approach I drafted above correct or not and can anybody tell me how Tomcat
/Jboss or other containers are implements JNDI. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You heard about the advantages of open source software? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can`t tell you how it works in JBoss or Tomcat, but it is quite easy to implement. Following simple logic, use a **ConcurrentHashMap** to store your objects. The access time to any object will be approximately O(1) which is perfect for look-ups. The hash table can be implemented as a static class field to be accessible to any part of the running application.

From here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/package-summary.html

"Context is the core interface for looking up, binding, unbinding, and renaming objects, and for creating and destroying subcontexts." In fact, it provides all the basic operations of HashMaps. Everything else is just an extension.

As a bonus, it will require you only 1 LOC instead of the commented line.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I just want to ensure on thing how does the two different JVM to transfer their object, using socket or other technology?